# ¿Cómo remplazar los valores de un array con los valores de otro PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo una consulta: ¿como podría combinar los valores de un array?. Me explico:

tengo 2 arrays, el primer array es :

```html
 Array ([0] => Array (
[proveedorId] => 1
[sucursalId] => 1 
[bancoId] => 0 
[creadoPor] => jromero 
[creadoFecha] => /Date(1496481777933-0000)/
[modificadoPor] => jromero 
[modificadoFecha] => /Date(1496784853423-0000)/ 
[tipoProveedor] => Proveedor 
[codigo] => JARB 
[nombre] => Jose A. Romero Bonilla 
[tipoPersona] => Juridica 
[documento] => RTN 
[documentoNo] => 123546546 
[telefono] => 832-335-9841
[email] => jbonilla@gmail.com 
[contacto] => Jose A. Romero
 [estado] => Activo
 )
 [1] => Array ( 
[proveedorId] => 2 
[sucursalId] => 1
[bancoId] => 0 
[creadoPor] => jromero 
[creadoFecha] => /Date(1496490462867-0000)/ 
[modificadoPor] => jromero 
[modificadoFecha] => /Date(1496785149400-0000)/ 
[tipoProveedor] => Proveedor 
[codigo] => wa 
[nombre] => Wilfredo 
[tipoPersona] => Natural 
[documento] => RTN 
[documentoNo] => 0801199422893
 [direccion1] => col. kennedy 
[ciudad] => tegucigalpa 
[dep_Est_Prov] => francisco morazan 
[codigoPostal] => 504 
[telefono] => 22222222 
[email] => josealeman@gmail.com 
[contacto] => jose aleman 
[estado] => Activo ) 
 )
```

el segundo array es :

```
Array 
(
 [0] => Array (
 [sucursalId] => 0 
 [nombre] =>  Sucursal0 ) 
 [1] => Array (
 [sucursalId] => 1 
 [nombre] =>  Sucursal1 ) 
 [2] => Array (
 [sucursalId] => 2 
 [nombre] =>  Sucursal2
```

)

como cambio el valor [sucursalId] del arreglo uno por el  [nombre] del segundo array para que quede como resultado [SucursalNombre] => Sucursal1 Dependiendo el codigo de scursal

Comment: `$array1[0]['sucursalNombre']=$array2[0]['nombre'];` ?

Comment: tu array 1 es un array de arrays, quieres que para cada array dentro del array 1 se cambia el id por el nombre?

Comment: si para cada array dentro del array 1 se cambia el id del array 1 por el nombre del array 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

con:

```
$array1[0]['sucursalNombre']=$array2[0]['nombre'];
```

agregas el `key` `['sucursalNombre']` con el valor de `$array2[0]['nombre']`.

y con:

```
unset($array1[0]['sucursalId']);
```

eliminas el registro `['sucursalId']`

luego solo usas un `for` para iterar

el ejemplo quedaría:

```
$array1=Array 
(
 0 => Array (
 'proveedorId' => 1 ,
 'sucursalId' => 1,
 'codigo' => 'JARB' ,
 'nombre' => 'Jose' ),
 1 => Array (
 'proveedorId' => 1 ,
 'sucursalId' => 1,
 'codigo' => 'Lurb' ,
 'nombre' => 'Luis' ),
);

$array2=Array 
(
 0 => Array (
 'sucursalId' => 1, 
 'nombre' =>  'Sucursal1' ) 
);
for ($i=0; $i<count($array1);i++){
    $array1[$i]['sucursalNombre']=$array2[0]['nombre'];
    unset($array1[$i]['sucursalId']);
}
var_dump($array1);
```

> array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { ["proveedorId"]=> int(1) ["codigo"]=>
>   string(4) "JARB" ["nombre"]=> string(4) "Jose" ["sucursalNombre"]=>
>   string(9) "Sucursal1" } [1]=> array(4) { ["proveedorId"]=> int(1)
>   ["codigo"]=> string(4) "Lurb" ["nombre"]=> string(4) "Luis"
>   ["sucursalNombre"]=> string(9) "Sucursal1" } }

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con `array_replace`:

```
$cambiar = array(2 => $array2["nombre"]);
array_replace($array1, $cambiar);
```

Esta función cambia elementos entre arrays.

Si quieres más información http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

Bueno la respuesta no era dificil

```html
   
   //el array html viene de la tabla proveedores
    $htmldatos = array();
    $htmldatos = ConectarAPI("proveedores/Activo");
   //el array sucursales biene de la tabla sucursales 
    $sucursalesArray =  array();
    $sucursalesArray = ConectarAPI("sucursales");
    $contador= 0;
    //recorremos el arreglo htmldatos
    foreach ($htmldatos as $valor)
    {
    //guardamos el Id en la variable
      $IdSucursalGuardada = $valor["sucursalId"];
      $NombreSucursal ="";

      foreach ($sucursalesArray as $val)
      {
            if($val["sucursalId"] = $IdSucursalGuardada)
            {
              $NombreSucursal = $val["nombre"];
            }

            if($val["sucursalId"] == 0)
            {
              $NombreSucursal = "N/A";
            }
      }

//Agregamos ["SucursalNombre"] al arreglo htmldatos
      $htmldatos[$contador]["SucursalNombre"] = $NombreSucursal;
      $contador++;
    
    }
```